# How to change the background color of the Highcharts(HighMaps in specific) dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts, highmaps

when a user selects a theme in a page,the backgroundcolor of the highchart should also change based on the user selection .
My code:

```
    var colorCode="#fff";



var chart1=new Highcharts.mapChart('geoMap', {
 chart: {

     backgroundColor:colorCode,
     type: 'map'


 },
 title: {
     text: 'US'
 },

 legend: {
     enabled: true
 },
......
......
......
$('#theme1').click(function() {
    // colorCode="default"
     colorCode={
               linearGradient: [0, 0, 500, 500],
               stops: [
                 [0, 'rgb(142, 158, 171)'],
                 [1, 'rgb(238, 242, 243)']
               ]
             }

chart1.redraw();
});
```

But the chart isn't getting refreshed so the colorCode is not getting applied. Any kind of suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Can you please give me the div's `ID` or `CLASS` which is holding highchart

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually assign the new color to the chart options

```
chart1.options.chart.backgroundColor = colorCode
```

i made a small fiddle that takes the color from a dropdown (which would emulate your user changing the theme) and sets it as the background of you chart http://jsfiddle.net/grLrmxhd/1/

Comment: In addition to your answer, it is also possible to use chart.update() method for changing chart options dynamically. I have prepared an example of changing chart's background color using chart.update: http://jsfiddle.net/grLrmxhd/2/